# How to get value from child table using eloquent in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two table : users and profile.
A user may have one or multiple profile. I want to access the combined data of both table: 'ID' in user table is foreign key in profile table

User model :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
   use Notifiable;

   protected $fillable = [
    'first_name','last_name', 'email', 'password','phone','user_type',
   ];

   protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
   ];

   public function profile()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(profile::class);
   }
}
```

Profile model is :

```
class profile extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = [
                    'id','relationship_status','dob','height',
                    'weight','primary_language'
                  ];
   protected $primaryKey = 'profile_id';

   public function User()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'id','id');
   }
}
```

Comment: would you tell more about what you want with an example

Comment: user `hasMany` profile or `hasOne` profile ?

Comment: from you question i found that your database structure id not right. where is user_id in profile table ?

Comment: i used same field name in profiles table, ID

Answer (score 2):

Change your user model profile relationship like this

User Model

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Profile::class); //assuming your user has single profile
}
```

Profile model

```
class Profile extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = [
                         'id', 'user_id', 'relationship_status','dob','height',
                         'weight','primary_language'
                         ];

   //add user_id field in profiles table
   //protected $primaryKey = 'profile_id'; //no need of this, because you have id field in profiles table

   public function user()
   {
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
   }
}
```

after that you can fetch data like this

```
$user = User::find(2);
dd($user);
dd($user->profile)
```

When fetching multiple users details, then use eager loading

```
$users = User::with('profile')->get();

foreach($users as $user){
   dd($user->profile)
}
```

Check details https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one